# Outputting values from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->load->library('opencloud');
$opencloud = new Opencloud;
$containers = $this->opencloud->list_containers();
print_r($containers);
```

The above code outputs the following array:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => .CDN_ACCESS_LOGS [count] => 2 [bytes]
>   => 606 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Michael Grigsby [count] => 9 [bytes] => 891976 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Random Photos [count] => 0 [bytes] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [name] => hello [count] => 10 [bytes] =>
>   1129257 ) [4] => Array ( [name] => hello_world [count] => 1 [bytes] =>
>   659737 ) [5] => Array ( [name] => hi [count] => 0 [bytes] => 0 ) )

When I echo out `$containers[1]['name']` I get: `Michael Grigsby`. My question is how do I get the script to output all of the `name` values rather than simply one?

Comment: use `for` or `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can echo the name of each array in this classic mode in PHP with a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($containers as $container){
  echo($container['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

foreach($mainarray as $onearray){

        echo $onearray['name'];

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop around the array with `for` loop in the following way:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($containers); $i++) {
    echo $containers[$i]['name'];
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a `foreach` loop to directly get the content without any manipulation of array indexes.